# Account based Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, tasks, microsoft-outlook-2013, to-do

I have two accounts in Outlook 2013, my work Exchange account and my personal Hotmail account.  I am trying to conditionally format the tasks and emails in my To-Do List based on which account they are in.  Here's a sample.

```
TASK SUBJECT           OUTLOOK DATA FILE   IN FOLDER   OWNER   DESIRED COLOUR
Fix that bug.          me@work.com         Tasks       Me      Black
Request for review.    me@work.com         Inbox               Black
Send birthday card.    me@hotmail.com      Tasks               Blue
Game patch released.   me@hotmail.com      Inbox               Blue
```

I have attempted to create the conditional format to turn the text blue:

> When **Outlook Data File** is (exactly) **me@hotmail.com**
>   Font colour **blue**
>
> *No effect.*

Similarly:

> When **Outlook Data File** contains **hotmail.com**
>   Font colour **blue**
>
> *No effect.*

I thought it could be a format ordering issue, but the following condition does change the text colour.  It colours all Hotmail items **and** flagged work emails, not quite what I want:

> When **Owner** is empty
>   Font colour **blue**
>
> *Font is blue for all Hotmail tasks, and flagged work emails.*

How can I conditionally format all Hotmail tasks and flagged emails?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

The **E-mail Account** field can be used.

The confusing part is it's listed under **All Mail Fields** but not **All Task Fields**, even though it applies to tasks as well.