# Prevent Outlook calendar conditional formating happening on iCal feed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, conditional-formatting

I've got two calendars in Outlook 2010:

1. My own calendar (which comes from the company exchange server)
2. My personal calendar (which comes from Google in the form of an iCal feed)

If I apply conditional formatting to appointments (eg. mark all appointments marked as free in grey) then the colouring is applied to both my Outlook calendar and my iCal calendar.

Is there any way to prevent my personal calendar from having these conditional formatting rules applied?

I've tried the rules `In folder`, `E-mail Account` (referenced [here](https://superuser.com/q/630750/46099)) and `Outlook Data File` but each of them just seem to turn the colouring off for all appointments - which means that either they don't work or I'm doing it wrongly.

Comment: are  these events in both calendars by chance? if so that could explain it

Comment: No they are different. For example, I have a weekly appointment to take out the trash in only my personal Google calendar (I'm forgetful) and it's marked as "free". When I apply the conditional formatting described above, it too ends up being coloured grey when I just want the coloured formatting to happen on my work Outlook calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, the rule you want is as follows:

`In Folder` `doesn't contain` `Personal`

Where `Personal` is the **display name** of the Internet Calendar you don't want the formatting to be applied to.

You can find the display name by looking at the entries within the "Other Calendars" section on the left hand side:

[image]